# Menú responsive no funciona en url amigables

Tags: jquery

Tengo todas las reglas de los estilos `css` y `js` de está manera, creo que le llama absoluta o relativa, no recuerdo:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/js/app.min.js"></script>
```

He abierto el código fuente desde el navegador y abierto los archivos enlazados y se abren correctamente, es decir se están llamando correctamente.

En el índice principal funciona, el menú responisve se abre al igual que en todos los demás enlaces, excepto los enlaces de url amigables de los productos, por ejemplo:

```
example.com/product/url-of-product-of-example/
```

Es curioso dado a que en esa misma `URL`, añado productos al carro por `ajax` y funciona, pero cuando trato de abrir dicho menú desde esa misma `URL amigable`, no funciona, no abre el menú, no entiendo porque.

```js
$(function() {
    $('.slideout-menu-toggle').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var slideoutMenu = $('.slideout-menu');
        var slideoutMenuWidth = $('.slideout-menu').width();
        $('.capa').toggleClass('visible');
        slideoutMenu.toggleClass("open");
    });
});
```

```css
.menu-responsive {
    /*display: none;*/
}
.slideout-menu {
    padding: 1em 1em;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: -300px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #fafafa; /*rgba(15, 23, 27, 0.85);*/
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
    color: #b3b3a3;
    z-index: 100;
}
.slideout-menu ul.system {
    justify-content: start;
}
.slideout-menu ul.system li {
    padding: 0;
}
.slideout-menu h3 {
    padding: 0.6em 0;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    font-weight: 400;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0.2em;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 1;
    color: #464646;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
.slideout-menu .slideout-menu-toggle:hover {
    color: #999;
}
span.slideout-menu-toggle {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.slideout-menu ul li {
    margin-top: 0.5em;
    padding: .2rem 0;
    padding-left: 1rem;
    padding-right: 1rem;
}
.capa {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    transition: all .5s cubic-bezier(0.39, 0.575, 0.565, 1);
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.slideout-menu.open {
    right: 0;
}
.capa.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}
.icon-menu {
    width: 60px;
    height: 50px;
    background-image: url(https://w7.pngwing.com/pngs/267/362/png-transparent-computer-icons-encapsulated-postscript-others-miscellaneous-button-icon-burger-menu.png);
}
.icon-menu {
  content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
            <nav class="nav flex justify-between">

                <div class="menu-responsive">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <span class="slideout-menu-toggle"><i class="icon-menu"></i></span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="slideout-menu">
                    <span href="#" class="slideout-menu-toggle">×</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/support/">Support</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/logout/">Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
    <div class="capa"></div>
```

Comment: Revisá la solapa "network/red" de las herramientas de desarrollo del explorador que estés utilizando. Si efectivamente no está cargando el archivo js, deberías ver un "404" junto a "app.min.js". Si por el contrario, el archivo si lo está cargando correctamente, entonces el problema viene por otro lado.

Comment: @azeós No sale nada :/ ningún error.